# Pyper error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, r, pyper

I'm trying to work with the pyper library in Python. I've been following along with the example [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2012/12/fractional-logit-model-with-python/), but I keep running into an error. It doesn't seem like the pyper library is working for me at all.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyper as pr

r = pr.R(use_pandas = True)
```

I get the following error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

I'm running it in a Juypter environment on Python 3. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested this, and I am sure it is related to your R installation and if your python kernel can find the R executable.
Make sure [R is installed](https://www.r-project.org/), and your system path variable contains the directory for the R binaries ("C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\bin", if you are using the latest version).
You can set this with a GUI in windows running "SystemPropertiesAdvanced" from the command prompt >  Environment Variables > And edit the Path variable within the System Variables to include the R bin directory. However it required a full PC restart for me to work in the Jupyter Notebook.